# Returning an assignment by creator of the classroom

Tags: google-classroom

I have created the assignment and assigned the `draft_grade` to the assignment by the creator of the classroom.

When I am trying to `return` an assignment by the creator of the classroom, I am getting this error `{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Precondition check failed.", "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION" } }`.

It is working fine, on the https://classroom.google.com pages. But it is giving this error to API only.

Please let me know, what would be the problem.

Comment: According to the docs, [FAILED_PRECONDITION](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Request.Errors) error happens when the requested action is not permitted because of some current state.